# Comparing two ranked list with scores

Tags: ranking, kendall-tau

I want to compare two ranked lists with items and their confidence scores assigned by the model. The lists are non-conjoint, i.e. can have different items. The number of items is the same for both lists.

For example;

List A

1. some 0.5
2. whole 0.32
3. great 0.26
4. all 0.14
5. same 0.08

List B

1. whole 0.62
2. all 0.32
3. great 0.19
4. some 0.18
5. new 0.02

I know I can use Kendall's tau for a similar problem. But the problem here is, I don't want to consider only the ranking but also the confidence score assign to each item. Is there a way to do that?